# Using a file fixture in a fixture file in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, fixtures

I’ve been looking for information about how to specify resources in the fixtures/files directory in my fixtures YAML files. For example, if I have the following fixture in fixtures/products.yml:

```
one:
  title: MyString
  description: MyText
  image_url: MyString
  price: 9.99
```

I have this test:

```
class ProductsControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  setup do
    @product = products(:one)
  end

  test "should get index" do
    get products_url
    assert_response :success
  end
...
```

This in products/index.html.erb:

```
...
    <% @products.each do |product| %>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <%= image_tag(product.image_url) %>
...
```

and this action in the products controller:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @products = Product.all
  end
...
```

I want to reference the file fixtures/files/image.png so that the URL and image are available for the test. How can I do that? is there a better way to do it?

I'm using Rails 6.0.3.4 and ruby 2.7.2

Comment: I'm not sure you can actually specify files in a fixture unless your model can just take a path instead of a file object. Fixtures in general are limited to the types available in YAML.

Comment: @max, I can use a URL, but still, I need to be able to specify it in the YAML file so that it will be available to the test, otherwise the `image_tag(product.image_url)` in the view fails.

Comment: Rails passes the fixture files through ERB before they are parsed so you can use something like `file_path: <%= file_fixture('image.jpg') %>`.

Comment: @max, the first method fails with `NoMethodError: undefined method 'file_fixture' for #<#<Class:0x00007ff9a0bd4560>:0x00007ff9a0bd43d0>`, but the second one worked. Thanks. If you write an answer I'd be happy to upvote it.

Comment: Using `Rails.root(...)`?

Comment: I ended up using this code in config/initializers/assets.rb for the test environment: ```Rails.application.config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/test/fixtures/files/assets"``` so I can just put the assets for tests there.